# ValueError: Could not locate the resource 'C:\Users\loginname\Desktop\2020\chatbot\.data\data.json'

Tags: python, chatbot, rasa

I am creating a small chatbot. I am getting an error while training my model.

The code is here:

```
from rasa_nlu.training_data import load_data
from rasa_nlu import config
from rasa_nlu.model import Trainer

def train_nlu(data, config, model_dir):
    training_data = load_data(data)
    trainer = Trainer(RasaNLUConfig(config))
    trainer.train(training_data)
    model_directory = trainer.persist(model_dir, fixed_model_name='weathernlu')
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    train_nlu('.data/data.json', 'config_spacy.json', './models/nlu')
```

Error Message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File “nlu_model.py”, line 14, in
train_nlu(‘.data/data.json’, ‘config_spacy.json’, ‘./models/nlu’)
File “nlu_model.py”, line 8, in train_nlu
training_data = load_data(data)
File “C:\Users\loginname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\rasa_nlu\training_data\loading.py”, line 50, in load_data
files = utils.list_files(resource_name)
File “C:\Users\loginname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\rasa_nlu\utils\__init__.py”, line 103, in list_files
return [fn for fn in list_directory(path) if os.path.isfile(fn)]
File “C:\Users\loginname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\rasa_nlu\utils\__init__.py”, line 95, in list_directory
“”.format(os.path.abspath(path)))
ValueError: Could not locate the resource ‘C:\Users\loginname\Desktop\2020\chatbot\.data\data.json’.
```

Can someone help me.

Comment: Are you sure the file "C:\Users\loginname\Desktop\2020\chatbot\.data\data.json" does exist? Could you open it in Python using `open(r'C:\Users\loginname\Desktop\2020\chatbot\.data\data.json')` for example?

Answer (score 0):

check path to your files: `'.data/data.json', 'config_spacy.json', './models/nlu'`
make sure that all of them in `'C:\Users\loginname\Desktop\2020\chatbot\'`
or you can use full path in `train_nlu()`